# SMARTY - stemmings - number of products (Prestashop)

Tags: php, numbers, smarty, prestashop

I've got the following problem. I'm making a shop in Prestashop CMS, which uses Smarty template engine. So there's a sentence, displaying a number of products. Now - in english language it's simple - you can make it like that:

```
{l s='Cart contains'} {$productNumber} {if $productNumber == 1}{l s='product'}{else}{l s='products'}{/if}
```

But this shop is made in polish language - and there starts the problem. It's much more complicated.It's like this:

1. For 1 product you have one word - "produkt"
2. For 2,3 and 4 products and every number that contains those
   numbers (like 22,23,24,32,33,34,152,153,154,242,243,244, etc.)
   another word - "produkty"
3. For everything above 4 (except those numbers in point 2) third
   word - "produktów"

So - how to write a smarty condition for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Just me being curious and not an answer. Does Smarty require you to add all that on only one line?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the logic required here is verbose enough and possibly reused enough to warrant a plugin.

```
function smarty_modifier_nb_products_to_str($nbProducts){
   if($nbProducts > 1){
      $numbers = str_split((string) $nbProducts);
      return count(array_intersect($numbers, array('2','3','4'))
        ? 'produkty'
        : 'produktów';
   } else {
     return 'produkt';
   }
}
```

With usage like:

```
{l s='Cart contains'} {nb_products_to_str($productNumber)}
```